# Ways to notify/alert the user in Firefox's WebExtensions

Tags: javascript, notifications, popup, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing cross-browser extension using WebExtensions API. It's focused on monitoring some HTTP request and blocking potentially malicious ones. I need to get user input for each blocked host (because it could have been falsely blocked and user might want to unblock it right away). Originally I wanted to use [popup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Popups), but then I found out, that popups are only allowed to be thrown up in User Action event handler, which is a problem, I need to to that independently on the user's action. After that I found second option - the Chrome's [notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications/NotificationOptions#buttons) API. But again, found out, that Firefox does not implement buttons in notifitacions (even though Chrome does). `OnClicked` event is supported for notification, but that's not enough (mainly because of users accidentally clicking on the notification to close it).

TL;DR - Looking for a way to alert/notify user and get the input from him by clicking on one of two presented buttons. Popups and Notifications does not seem like sufficient way.

Can you suggest ways to implement desired behaviour?

Possible solutions:

1) Injecting content script that implements popup window and communicates via messages with bacgkround script.

2) Simulating animation of extension's icon to draw user's attention.

Comment: a content sscript injected into the page?

Comment: Hmm yes, that would work. Good suggestion.

Comment: Simulate an animation in the icon using Canvas or a sequence of static images to draw user's attention so they click the icon and perform the action.

Comment: Okey, that's another way. It doesn't make sure, that user really sees the popup/alert though. But in case, these are not absolutely urgent, it's clean solution. Will keep that in mind, Thanks for suggestion.